# Is trailers frame after data frame possible in HTTP/2?

Tags: http-headers, http2, http-protocols

Is it possible in HTTP/2 that a data frame is received with END_STREAM flag, and later a trailers frame will be received? In other words, will a frame with END_STREAM also indicate that no other frame will be sent?
Also, must a trailers frame (Which is practically headers frame) set END_STREAM?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible in HTTP/2 that a data frame is received with END_STREAM flag, and later a trailers frame will be received?

No. When a frame with END_STREAM is received, the stream enters the "half-closed (remote)" state.

This is specified in section 5.1 of RFC 7540, where it says:

> half-closed (remote):
> A stream that is "half-closed (remote)" is no longer being used by
> the peer to send frames.  In this state, an endpoint is no longer
> obligated to maintain a receiver flow-control window.
> If an endpoint receives additional frames, other than
> WINDOW_UPDATE, PRIORITY, or RST_STREAM, for a stream that is in
> this state, it MUST respond with a stream error (Section 5.4.2) of
> type STREAM_CLOSED.